# Detect if mouse stop moving vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, timer, mouse, groupbox

I would like to stop the `timer` whenever a mouse stops moving inside a `groupbox`

As of now, I start the timer when the mouse hover at the groupbox and stops it when it leaves the group box.

```
Private Sub gbxMouseMap_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles gbxMouseMap.MouseHover
    Timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub gbxMouseMap_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles gbxMouseMap.MouseLeave
    Timer.Stop()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MouseMove event set a class varible named *LastMoveTime* to the current timer elapsed time. In the MouseHover event check to see if *LastMoveTime* has reached the timeout period, if so stop the timer.

I will get you started...

```
Private LastMoveTime As DateTime
Private MouseTimeoutMilliseconds as Integer = 500 


'put inside hover

If  LastMoveTime.AddMilliseconds(MouseTimeoutMilliseconds) < Now Then
 Timer.Stop()
Else
 Timer.Start()
End if
```

Comment: I'll try that and report back for progress.

Comment: Okay, I understand the logic but I don't know now how to do it. Could you please provide me some code to where I can start. Thanks. @Michael

Comment: I tried, `Timer.Interval = LastMoveTime.TimeOfDay.Milliseconds` on MouseMove event and it gave me an error.

`Value '0' is not a valid value for Interval. Interval must be greater than 0.
Parameter name: Interval` @Michael

Comment: Why are you changing the interval in the MouseMove event?

Comment: `In the MouseMove event set the current timer time to a class varible named LastMoveTime`, so I did. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I said it backwards and have edited the answer to fix my mistake. Another note Timer.Interval is how often the timer fires, it's not the timer time.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent having to handle this for many controls you can rearrange things a bit and cache the information needed to know if cursor has moved and how long the idle time is, to do this you need a Point variable and a Date variable. The Timer needs to tick all the time. In addition, to balance the cursor Show/Hide calls you need a variable to keep track of its visibility state. Here is the complete code sample:

`Private loc As Point, idle As Date, hidden As Boolean`,
`Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If loc <> Cursor.Position Then
        If hidden Then
            Cursor.Show()
            hidden = False
        End If
        loc = Cursor.Position
        idle = Date.Now
    ElseIf Not hidden AndAlso (Date.Now - idle).TotalSeconds > 3 Then`

        `Cursor.Hide()
        hidden = True
    End If
End Sub`

This Timer can tick each 1/2-1 seconds depending on how responsive you want it, the idle time is set to 3 seconds. The code should be easy to understand when you read it and give it some thought, if not ask